# Alter table schema based on another table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

In sql if i had 2 databases where each had similar columns but not exactly the same schema , is there a built in way to alter the schema of a table in `database2` make it similar to the schema in of a table `database1`?

considering that the column type and column name and default value are the factors to decide if 2 columns match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no built in functionality for doing this, you will either have to do it manually or use a comparison tool such as [RedGate SQL Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/) or [Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd193250%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).